# fine-uploader resubmit parameters but not file

Tags: callback, set, user-input, parameters, fine-uploader

I'm using fine-uploader to take multiple (large) files and pass the filename along with an additional user-input parameter. I do that by creating a text input box (called 'allele_freq') next to each file and I pass the filename and the allele_freq parameter to my cgi script.
What happens next (or what will happen next) is that I analyse the data in the file, using the allele_freq parameter and then some images are returned to the page for the user to look at.
If the user wants to re-analyse the data with a new allele_freq, all I want to do is to pass the filename along with the new allele_freq, i.e. I don't want to have to upload the file again.
I've pasted my working code below (it uploads multiple files along with user input for each file) and then the code that I can't get to work (it produces a 'resubmit' button, but doesn't appear to do anything), along with some comments/musings within the code.
Any information on how I would do this will be gratefully received. I'm very new to both fine-uploader and Javascript (as you can probably tell), so please feel free to criticise (constructively of course!) any of my code.
Many thanks,
Graham

```
<link href="fineuploader/fineuploader-3.6.4.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="fineuploader/jquery-2.0.1.js"></script>
<script src="fineuploader/jquery.fineuploader-3.6.4.js"></script>

<div id="multiFineUploader"></div>
<div id="triggeredUpload" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Upload now
</div>
<script>
$('#multiFineUploader').fineUploader({
request: {
    endpoint: 'src/lib/upload.cgi'
},
autoUpload: false,
 text: {
uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Select Files'
}
})
.on('submitted', function(event, id, name) {
    var fileItemContainer = $(this).fineUploader('getItemByFileId', id);
    $(fileItemContainer)
    .append('<input type="text" name="allele_freq">');
})
.on('upload', function(event, id, name) {
    var fileItemContainer = $(this).fineUploader('getItemByFileId', id),
    enteredAlleleFreq = $(fileItemContainer).find('INPUT[name="allele_freq"]').val();
    $(this).fineUploader('setParams', {allele_freq: enteredAlleleFreq}, id);
});

$('#triggeredUpload').click(function() {
    $('#multiFineUploader').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');

});
</script>
```

### above code works fine

### code below doesn't

```
<div id="resubmitFreqs"></div>
<div id="retry" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 10px;">
<i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Resubmit
</div>
<script>
$('#resubmitFreqs').fineUploader({
request: {
            //use a different script as shouldn't need to handle all the upload stuff
    endpoint: 'src/lib/resubmit.cgi'
}
)}
//get the information from the allele_freq box. Should it still be in scope?? If not, how do I get at it?
.on('upload', function(event, id, name) {
    var fileItemContainer = $(this).fineUploader('getItemByFileId', id),
    enteredAlleleFreq = $(fileItemContainer).find('INPUT[name="allele_freq"]').val();
    $(this).fineUploader('setParams', {allele_freq: enteredAlleleFreq}, id);
});
$('#retry').click(function() {
            //I presumably don't want to use 'uploadStoredFiles', but I'm not sure how to post my new parameters into the resubmit.cgi server-side script
    $('#resubmitFreqs').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to  bend Fine Uploader into something that it is not.  Fine Uploader should probably not be involved with this step of your process, as its job is to upload files to your server.  It is not meant to be an all-in-one web application.  If you want to send additional data to your server at some point in time after the file has been sent, simply send a POST request with that data via XHR.